# VB.NET replace codeblock in file found by variable

Tags: regex, vb.net

Let's assume I have files in a local Github and I need to replace this code

```
    bool CBlock::ReadFromDisk(const CBlockIndex* pindex, bool fReadTransactions)
{
    if (!fReadTransactions)
    {
        *this = pindex->GetBlockHeader();
        return true;
    }
    if (!ReadFromDisk(pindex->nFile, pindex->nBlockPos, fReadTransactions))
        return false;
    if (GetHash() != pindex->GetBlockHash())
        return error("CBlock::ReadFromDisk() : GetHash() doesn't match index");
    return true;
}
```

I'm looking for a way to 'scan' the files and match the initial

```
bool CBlock::ReadFromDisk(const CBlockIndex* pindex, bool fReadTransactions)
```

and replace the code between the brackets {} entirely.

So the only part I know about the blocks I need to replace are the declarations.

Comment: .NET's regex engine does not support recursive patterns (as some other flavors do), but it does support [balanced groups](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timart/archive/2013/05/14/nested-recursive-regex-and-net-balancing-groups-detect-a-function-with-a-regex.aspx) which allows you to do roughly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

To match everything between ( and ) you can use:

```
(?<=bool CBlock::ReadFromDisk\().*?(?=\))
```

---

```
Dim ResultString As String
Try
    ResultString = Regex.Replace(SubjectString, "(?<=bool CBlock::ReadFromDisk\().*?(?=\))", "replacement_text_here", RegexOptions.Multiline)
Catch ex As ArgumentException
    'Syntax error in the regular expression
End Try
```

---

To match everything between { and } you can use:

```
(?<=bool CBlock::ReadFromDisk\(const CBlockIndex\* pindex, bool fReadTransactions\)\s*\{)(?:[^{}]|(?<open>{)|(?<-open>}))+(?(open)(?!))(?=\})
```

---

```
Dim ResultString As String
Try
    ResultString = Regex.Replace(SubjectString, "(?<=bool CBlock::ReadFromDisk\(const CBlockIndex\* pindex, bool fReadTransactions\)\s*\{)(?:[^{}]|(?<open>{)|(?<-open>}))+(?(open)(?!))(?=\})", "replacement_text_here")
Catch ex As ArgumentException
    'Syntax error in the regular expression
End Try
```

Comment: How can i apply this regex to curly brackets, like {} to replace the code inside them?

Comment: Still no luck to apply the above regex by @Andie2302 to capture everything between the {} brackets with the leading text